# Why are the explicit time integrators unable to capture a simple first order ODE behavior?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

[image: Numerical Integration]

Please look at the image to understand the issue.

I have tried to use simple time integration schemes to model the behavior of a simple initial value problem. I am unable to understand the error accumulation with time, i have also tried with a finer timestep of 1e-6, but got the similar results.

Answer (score 2):

If $y(0) = -24/37 + \delta$ then the solution is $\delta e^{0.5t} - \frac{24}{37}\cos(3t) - \frac{4}{37}\sin(3t)$. Notice that if $\delta\neq 0$ that we now have an exponential term. So after the first step if there is any error you will pick up that exponential term in your solution. Notice that the curves after 30 seconds are proportional to $-e^{0.5t}$ which is the same rate as the $\delta e^{0.5t}$ term you picked up because of the error you have accumulated in your integration step.

Comment: Thank you. So, is there any way to better implement these methods numerically, for exponential based solutions ? I know we could use implicit integration schemes, but want to know if.